# Chrome Extension Working only for one URL

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

i am creating a chrome extension
i created a diretory with 
1.background.js 2.icon.png 3.icon2.png 4.manifest.json 5.myscript.js

my manifest.json code is

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [ "storage"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

1. code for myscript.js which is content script is

   document.body.innerHTML=''+document.body.innerHTML+'' ;
           var iframe = document.getElementById("frame1");
           function addingevent(){
           chrome.extension.sendMessage({change: "icon"}, function(response) {
             console.log(response.resp);
           });

   ```
       }
       iframe.onload = function(){

       var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
       if(iframeDocument != null)
       {var bb=iframeDocument.getElementById('mybutton');
       if(bb != null)
       {
       bb.addEventListener("click",addingevent,false)
       alert("Hello World");

       }}

       }
   ```

and the code for background.js is

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

    console.log("from a content script:from the extension");

chrome.storage.local.get("icon",function(val){

if(val.icon == "icon1")
{chrome.browserAction.setIcon({"path" :"icon2.png"},function(){});
chrome.storage.local.set({"icon":"icon"},function(){});
}
else
{chrome.browserAction.setIcon({"path" :"icon.png"},function(){});

chrome.storage.local.set({"icon":"icon1"},function(){});

}

});

sendResponse({resp: "success"});

  });
```

objective of this extension is when user click on the button which is in the frame loaded from url http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/  icon should be toggled between icon.png and icon2.png

this extension works perfectly when i load it in webpage with url http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/ there is frame created and when i click button it is changing icon but when i open url stackoverflow.com then frame is created and showing a button in it,but when i click on the button icon remains same i am expecting that icon will be changed irrespective of url why its not changing in other url??please specify the reason

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues

- Do you expect a DOM Element with id `frame1` to exist on http://stackoverflow.com
  document.getElementById("frame1");
- What is significance of `document.body.innerHTML=''+document.body.innerHTML+'';`?

Comment: document.body.innerHTML='<div>< iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="10%" src="http://onemoredemo.appspot.com/"></ iframe><br/>'+document.body.innerHTML+'</div>' ;

Comment: i am using javascript adding frame1 and then getting it

Comment: due to some formatting reason it had been omitted now please reply

Comment: @RiteshMehandiratta: If you have difficulty in formatting code, can you link it to [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com/), it will give me clear picture.